# Updating sql probleme with caractere

Tags: sql-update

I'm sorry for my bad english, I have a little problem but i don't understand how to solve it.

When I do SQL update, I have one question mark `?` which appears in the field

Here is the code

```
public function FooterUpdate($footer_text, $client_id) {
$connection = new Connection;
$db = $connection->openConnection();
$req = $db->prepare("UPDATE jcmsi_parametre SET footer_text = :footer_text WHERE client_id = :client_id");
$req->bindValue(':footer_text', $footer_text);
$req->bindValue(':client_id', $client_id);
$req->execute();}
```

The text before insert

```
<p><em class="fa fa-arrow-right"></em><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></p>
```

The text after insert

```
<p><em class="fa fa-arrow-right"></em><a href="contact.php" >Contact?</a></p>
```

After the insert query, I have the word Contact with the question mark `?`.
I try echo $footer_text just before update and the text is ok, but not in sql

If you have an idea
Thank you
Didier